# how do I use UTC +14:00 in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to use [utc+14:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00) in my rails app , but

```
rake time:zones:all
```

shows up to utc+13:00 only . is there any workaround to use this timezone ?

Answer (score 1):

Rails time zones are a facade around the [tzinfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/), which uses IANA/Olson time zones.

You probably want either the zone `"Pacific/Kiritimati"`, which is in UTC+14 all year, or perhaps `"Pacific/Apia"`, which is in UTC+13 most of the year and in UTC+14 for daylight saving time.

Read the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) about Rails time zones, then take a look at [the mapping constant](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html).  You'll see that `"Pacific/Apia"` is mapped to the Rails name of `"Samoa"`, but `"Pacific/Kiritimati"` is not in the map.

The best advice I can offer is to use the TzInfo gem directly, and *not* use Rails time zone "friendly" names.